# How to keep syncronized an image and its text heading to occupy always the same width when/after resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to have in an HTML page an image and immediately beneath it a text field that has the same width as the image?

Yes, I know this is possible. But here comes the interesting part:

I want that when I am resizing (horizontally) the browser window, both the image and its heading re-size *synchronously* to the same width.

Is this possible to specify completely using CSS?

Or, if not possible with CSS only, can this be done with Javascript in an efficient way?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked into the fact that you can use percentages with CSS widths?

Comment: please post your code or live demo here how you are doing we wants to see than we will be able to tell you the solutions........

Comment: Just set the same width for the text field and the image?

Comment: @Ivan: I have tried placing both the image and the text (which is in its own `div`) in a common parent `div` and specifying for this parent `div` "display: inline-block" . This seems to work, however the image isn't resized (scaled down) when resizing/decreasing-the-width, but instead it is cropped. Another thing I tried was to set maxwidth for the `div` containing the text -- this doesn't produce the wanted effect at all.

Comment: @sevenseacat, Just specifying the same fixed width results in cropping the image and the text div, when resizing to decrease the width. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/aA78w/)?

HTML:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /><br/>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... </p>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
img, p {
 margin:0px auto;
    width: 50%;
}​
```

This is a really basic example of how to use CSS to have the `img` tag and `p` tag have the same percentage width.

Comment: Ivan, This is almost what I need, however I need the text to be left-alligned to the image and to occupy an area best with a colored backgound (say white on black) so that this area has the same vertical borders as the image itself -- at any moment during the resizing. Is this possible?

Comment: @curious Yes, I recommend looking into some CSS tutorials as what you are asking for are basic things that CSS can handle.

Comment: I performed a search and didn't find anything like this -- there are questions *separately* about either resizing an image or resizing text, but not about doing this in a synchronized way. Could you, please, provide a link to such material?